# Getting an attribute error when trying to serialize an object to JSON using Python and Selenium

Tags: python, json, selenium, serialization

I am getting the following error:

```
return json.dumps(obj, default=lambda o: o.__dict__)
AttributeError: 'mappingproxy' object has no attribute '__dict__'
```

Here is main:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from pages.cmc_home_page import CMCHomePage
from selenium import webdriver
import open_tagged_tickets

def get_driver():
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
    cmc_home_page = CMCHomePage(driver=browser)
    return cmc_home_page

def main():
    cmc_home_page=get_driver()
    cmc_home_page.go()
    open_tagged_tickets.open_tagged_tickets(cmc_home_page)
    
main()
```

Here is the open_tagged_tickets function:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
import json

def open_tagged_tickets(driver):
    iframe=driver.iframe()
    driver = json.dumps(driver.toJson(), indent=4)
    driver.switch_to_iframe(iframe)
```

Here is the CMCHomePage class:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from pages.base_element import BaseElement
from pages.base_page import BasePage
from pages.locator import Locator
import json

class CMCHomePage(BasePage):

    def iframe(self):
        locator = Locator(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value="iframe[id='main_body'][name='main_body']")
        return BaseElement(driver=self.driver, locator=locator)

    def last_elem_to_load(self):
        locator = Locator(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value="tr[role='row']")
        return BaseElement(driver=self.driver, locator=locator)

    def toJson(obj):
        return json.dumps(obj, default=lambda o: o.__dict__)

    def switch_to_iframe(self, frame):
        self.driver.switch_to.frame(frame)
```

It imports the following two classes:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

class BaseElement(object):
    def __init__(self, driver, locator):
        self.driver = driver
        self.locator = locator

        self.web_element = None
        self.find()

    def find(self):
        element = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 30).until(
            EC.visibility_of_element_located(locator=self.locator)
        )
        self.web_element = element
        return None

    def input_text(self, txt):
        self.web_element.send_keys(txt)
        return None

    def click(self):
        element = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 30).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable(locator=self.locator)
        )
        element.click()
        return None

    def attribute(self, attr_name):
        attribute = self.web_element.get_attribute(attr_name)
        return attribute
    
    @property
    def text(self):
        text = self.web_element.text
        return text

class BasePage(object):

    url = None

    def __init__(self, driver):
        self.driver = driver

    def go(self):
        self.driver.get(self.url)
```

And I do not know why I am having this issue. I just wanna switch to an iframe so the program can continue running. It worked well when I was just using functions but then I decided to go ahead and go object oriented. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Hey what are you trying to do?

Comment: Can you try doing json.dumps(drive.__dict__) ?

Comment: It seems like it will not work because the above object has no __dict__ attribute.

Comment: When I try this:

 'def toJson(self):
        json.dumps(self.__dict__))' 

I get this:

' File "C:\RoboDK\Python37\lib\json\encoder.py", line 179, in default
    raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
TypeError: Object of type WebDriver is not JSON serializable'

Comment: Still getting use to the comment formatting here.

Comment: TypeError: Object of type WebDriver is not JSON serializable

Comment: That is the new error after I tried:  json.dumps(drive.__dict__)

Comment: This doesnt work either: driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).